# Looping through nested arrays in php 7.2

Tags: php, lumen

I am trying to access values in a nested array that I send to my API but when do something like $data['inputs']{0} it only gives me back the first letter of the key when what I want is the whole value of the value and not the key but if I try something like $data['inputs']['type'] it gives me an offset error I ament sure how to correctly access the values the way I need to

```
public function saveEdit(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $unsanitizedData = $request->all();
        $data = [];
        $fid = $unsanitizedData['formId'];
        $data['form_name'] = json_encode($unsanitizedData['cred']['name']);
        $data['org'] = json_encode($unsanitizedData['cred']['organization']);
        $data['updated_by'] = json_encode($unsanitizedData['updatedBy']);
        $data['user_id'] = json_encode($unsanitizedData['id']);
        $data['activated'] = json_encode($unsanitizedData['cred']['activated']);
        $data['inputs'] = json_encode($unsanitizedData['cred']['inputs']);
        $pattren = array("[","]","'",'"',"/","\\");
        $data = str_replace($pattren,'', $data);
        foreach ($unsanitizedData as $st) {
            admin_form::where('id', $fid)->update([
                'form_name' => $data['form_name'],
                'org' => $data['org'],
                'updated_by' => $data['updated_by'],
                'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
                'activated' => $data['activated']
                ]);
                foreach ($data['inputs'] as $input) {
                    admin_form_fields::where('form_id', $fid)->update([
                        'type' => $input,
                        'name' => $input
                    ]);
                }
        }


        $res['status'] = true;
        $res['message'] = 'Success';
        return response($res, 200);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $res['status'] = false;
        $res['message'] = $ex->getMessage();
        return response($res, 500);
    }
}
```

I thought if I use a foreach loop inside another foreach loop it would work because its a nested array so loop through the main one and then through the nested one but that did also not work

Data Structure when I do a data dump:

```
array:6 [
    "form_name"  => "Testname",
    "org"        => "TestOrg",
    "updated_by" => "test",
    "user_id"    => "29",
    "activated"  => "false",
    "inputs"     => "{type:number,name:Phone},{type:input,name:Name},{type:input,name:Address},{type:email,name:Email}"
]
```

Comment: _“but when do something like $data['inputs']{0} it only gives me back the first letter of the key”_ - well then `$data['inputs']` is not an array, but a string value in the first place …

Comment: Your `inputs` value _is_ a string value. You need to _decode_ the JSON it contains first, before you can access anything inside of it specifically. Right now, you do not even _have_ a “nested array”.

Comment: Why do you `json_encode()` your data, you do not need to do this!  This should remove your error as well!

Comment: I need json encode because If I dont use it lumen gives me an array to string conversion error and I havent been able to get an answer to another way to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `$data['inputs']` is a JSON encoded string from which you have removed the `[` and `]` characters so when you try to access its first element it's the first char (since strings are *kind of* arrays of strings in PHP, they are really array of strings in C).

The problem is that you call `json_encode()` in the first place. If it's how you sanitize input, you're doing it wrong. Since you're using an ORM, there's no real need to manually sanitize the input. Just keep your input as sent by the client and perform all your operations then use them unsanitized in the QueryBuilder

Comment: The only reason i am using json_encode is that if I don't and try to run an update statment I get an array to string conversion error and encoding the data is the only way I have found that will allow me to save it in the DB

Comment: I got rid of some other code and the JSON encode for inputs to turn it back into an array and it is working correctly now thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you just need to use `json_decode($data['inputs'])` since your array is in fact just a string :)